# eclipse unable edit javascript include path

Tags: eclipse, properties, include-path, eclipse-wtp

[Client-side JavaScript Include Path Excluded Edit window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQUbZ.png)

I try to exclude some js files from the path. Project -> Properties -> Client-side JavaScript -> Include Path -> Source. I choose a folder and "Excluded" line, press "Edit" The window that opens is totally irresponsive. I can't even close it. I go back to the "Properties for [my project]" window, close it. Then the "Inclusion and exclusion patterns" window become responsive, but when I add a pattern there, it wouldn't save.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=581996

Comment: What is your question? You already reported it. Can you propose a patch for it?